# Making database backup using routines and procedures

Tags: mysql, database

I want to backup my MySQL database , can I do it by using procedures or routines. I mean if i call a procedure, and pass the path where the file is to be exported to the procedure, then the procedure will make the backup. How can I write such a procedure or routine.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL itself cannot make backup, you should do it from the outside, e.g. run [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html) or another client program. But for your case (...using routines and procedures) you could try to use [user-defined function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-function-udf.html), it may help you to run backup process.